# Getting the ID of a particular user

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The code below is a php code where i have retrieved data from a database,the code is executing well .My main problem is,on click this link 'send offer' in the following reference link (send offer),i need to get only the id of the particular data without loading to another page and loop it with jquery.For instance on click the id='buyerRequest',i need to  insert data of that  user into the database without loading the page and in addtion to disable the other links.

The code below is a php code where i have retrieved data from a database,the code is executing well .My main problem is,on click this link 'send offer' in the following reference link (send offer),i need to get only the id of the particular data without loading to another page and loop it with jquery.For instance on click the id='buyerRequest',i need to  insert data of that  user into the database without loading the page and in addtion to disable the other links.

```
 <?php
            require'php/connection.php';
            $user_name=getUserField('user_name');

            $query="SELECT * FROM `place_order` where `buyer_name` != '$user_name' order by `order_id` DESC";
            if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
                echo"<table id='table_request'>";
                echo"<tr id='tr_request'>";
                    echo"<td>Date</td>";
                    echo"<td>Order Description</td>";
                    echo"<td>Bid</td>";
                    echo"<td>Order By</td>";
                    echo"<td>Send Offer</td>";
                echo"<br></tr>";

            while($fetch_num=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
                echo"<tr id='fetch_request'>";
                    echo"<td>".$fetch_num['current_date'].'</td>';
                    echo"<td>". $fetch_num['desc_order'].'</td>';
                    echo"<td>". $fetch_num['order_id'].'</td>';
                    echo"<td>". $fetch_num['buyer_name']."</td>";
                    echo"<td id='td_request'><a  id='buyerRequest' href='SendingOffer.php?id=".$fetch_num['order_id']." ' >send offer</a></td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";
            }
            ?>



**Jquery code**
$('#buyerRequest').click(function(){
$('#id').each(function()
{
var id=$(this).attr('id');
alert(id);
});
});
```

Comment: It looks like you’re generating more than one element with the same ID. That’s bad. You should change that when you can.

Comment: <a  id='buyerRequest' href='SendingOffer.php?id=".$fetch_num['order_id']." ' >send offer</a> with this code how can i get individual id=".$fetch_num['order_id']." with jquery

Comment: Thanks it has worked.Let me ask,i need to disable the value with other

Comment: Thanks it has worked.Let me ask,i need to disable the elements on click a total of ten element

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<a id='id_".$fetch_num['order_id']."' class="buyerRequest" href='#'>send offer</a>

$('.buyerRequest').click(function(){

    var id=$(this).attr('id').replace('id_','');
    alert(id);
    var data1 = {id: id};
            jQuery.ajax({
                data:data1,
                type:'POST',
                url: 'SendingOffer.php',//set full url 
                success:function(strHTML)
                {
                    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');//this is disable a link you want to clicked
                }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks it has worked.Let me ask,i need to disable the elements on click a total of ten element

Comment: @user3800343 you want to store a click of column records?

Comment: Thanks have gotten the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class='buyerRequest' data-id='".$fetch_num['order_id']."' href='SendingOffer.php?id=".$fetch_num['order_id']." ' >send offer</a>
```

Adding data attribute to element makes thing easier ( data-id )

```
$('.buyerRequest').click(function(){
    var order_id = $(this).data('id');
    alert("Order_id: " + order_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='buyerRequest' data-id='".$fetch_num['order_id']."' href='SendingOffer.php?id=".$fetch_num['order_id']." ' >offer sent</a>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#table_request tbody").on('click', '#buyerRequest', function(event) {
            var id=jQuery(this).data("id");
            alert(id);
            });
    });
```

Please Use tbody in your table.I think it will help you.

Comment: please if you will not mind,i need on click the send offer,the text changes to offer sent,can you please aid me in doing so

Comment: Please check my post i just edit the code.If it run please reply me

Comment: The code is not running,send offer is not changing to offer sent